# Control the range between min and max value in Sencha touch Chart

Tags: extjs, charts, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

[image]

In this picture the range is 3 plotted by library based on maximum data value. I need to change the interval. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            style: {
                estStepSize: 10
                   },
```

estStepSize use to control the range of xaxis.